# ASP.Net: Get IP Address of VMware client in load balancer environment

Tags: asp.net, webforms, vmware

Our configuration has 2 IIS web servers connected to 2 F5 load balancers.  Our applications are ASP.Net WebForms 4.5+.  Below is our code.

```
    public static string GetIpAddress()
    {
        var localContext = HttpContext.Current;
        string ipList = localContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipList))
        {
            return ipList.Split(',')[0];
        }
        return localContext.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
```

This code works correctly when accessing the load balanced site using physical computers.  Accessing a test server that doesn't use the load balancers using the VDI also works correctly.

Our problem is that when we access the load-balanced site using our VDI, this function returns the server address.

We need to be able to get the IP address of the VDI in the load balancer environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that our load balancers were misconfigured and not passing on the clients VDI IP addresses.